# Which is the better way to assign function for item in Flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am wondering which is the right way to assign `onPress` function for the `FlatList` item in React-Native. My mentor has explained for me that maybe I missed the knowledge of "delegate/closure/block" definition in OOP, I had read it but until now I still cannot figure it out by myself. This is the detail:

I have a screen named **Menu** – this menu has a `<FlatList>` which contains multiple `<MenuItem>`, each `<MenuItem>` has a toggle button to "add item to cart" or "remove item for cart" (click to add – click again to remove). I seperate `<MenuItem>` to another file so my current folder-tree looks like this:

```
__Menu
|  |_MenuItem
|       |__index.js
|
|__index.js
```

**And this is my mentor's approach:**

He defined a function named `_onToggleCart` in `Menu/index.js` like this:

```
_onToggleCart = (selected) => {
    if(selected == false){
      this.props.addItemToCart()
    }else{
      this.props.removeItemFromCart()
    }
}

<FlatList
  data={data}
  initialNumToRender={6}
  extraData={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <MenuItem item={item} isFinalItem={index == data.length - 1} navigation={navigation} onPress={this._onToggleCart} />}
/>
```

`Menu/MenuItem/index.js` looks like this:

```
...
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
const { id, imgURL, name, desciption, total } = item

_onChangeCart = () => {
    setSelected(!selected)
    onPress(selected)
}
...
<TouchableOpacity>
  ...
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onChangeCart}>
      ...
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**And this is my approach:**

In `Menu/index.js` I do not assign any function to `<MenuItem>`, so I don't have a function `_onToggleCart` and also don't have `onPress` props. It looks like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  initialNumToRender={6}
  extraData={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => <MenuItem item={item} isFinalItem={index == data.length - 1} navigation={navigation} />}
/>
```

In `Menu/MenuItem/index.js` to check the condition in `_onChageCart` like this:

```
...
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
const { id, imgURL, name, desciption, total } = item

_onChangeCart = () => {
    if(selected == false){
      this.props.addItemToCart()
    }else{
      this.props.removeItemFromCart()
    }
}
...
<TouchableOpacity>
  ...
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onChangeCart}>
      ...
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Can anyone help me what is different between them and which is better?

Comment: I would do your approach because it is more organized that way. I don't know if there are any significant differences other than organization.

Comment: It depends on what state/props the callback is operating on.  In your mentor's example it is clearly a callback meant to operate on the flatlist dataset whereas in your example the callback will operate on the individual element.  Right now, in both, it is a contrived example, but if say you *actually* wanted to add or remove then you would likely want to also pass the index and in that case, your mentor's example is the one that is easily extended to do that, your example would require a larger refactor to achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference from you component and the one of your *mentor* is that he passes a `onPress` prop to `MenuItem`. What difference does this makes?

Well, in your example, if you need to add more action on the `MenuItem` press, how do you do? You can't do it, but the way your *mentor* did, you can add more functionality (call one more function) to the `MenuItem` because he call `props.onPress`.

You mentor did a more flexible component, wich maybe can grow easier, your component is more fixed.

Wich one is better? Now that is up to you and the structure of your project.

Comment: Ok now it is clealier. So as I understand we should follow the way my mentor did because it is easier to grow in the future. 
Ex: I need to edit the function to do not only adding/removing but also do something relate with Menu/index.js component's state - and it cannot be done with my approach (or become flexible component unnecessary ). Do I understand correct?

Comment: You can do it with your approach, but it will need more refactor then your *mentor* approach